# Exchange web server more than, 1000 items

Tags: exchangewebservices

i try to get more than 1000 contacts, and i have more than 10000, and microsoft EWS only let me to get 1000 items (contacts).
 ContactsFolder contactsFolder = ContactsFolder.Bind(this.service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts,new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly,FolderSchema.TotalCount));

```
            ItemView view = new ItemView(contactsFolder.TotalCount);

            //ItemView view = new ItemView(1000,0,OffsetBasePoint.Beginning+1);

            service.TraceEnabled = false;
            FindItemsResults<Item> fiResults = null;
            do
            {
                fiResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);
                PropertySet itItemPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
                ContactSchema.GivenName,
                ContactSchema.Surname,
                ContactSchema.AssistantPhone,
                ContactSchema.BusinessPhone,
                ContactSchema.BusinessPhone2,
                ContactSchema.CarPhone,
                ContactSchema.CompanyMainPhone,
                ContactSchema.HomePhone,
                ContactSchema.HomePhone2,
                ContactSchema.MobilePhone,
                ContactSchema.OtherTelephone,
                ContactSchema.Pager,
                ContactSchema.PrimaryPhone,
                ContactSchema.CompanyName,
                ContactSchema.BusinessFax,
                ContactSchema.Id);

                view.Offset += fiResults.Items.Count;
            } while (fiResults.MoreAvailable == true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the offset for getting more items. Microsoft has an article how to do that, and I even see a commented part in your code. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633698(v=exchg.80).aspx